# Convert argument to LPWSTR CreateProcess

Tags: c++

I am trying to perform some actions using `cmd.exe` but I want to hide `cmd.exe`.  When I tried to use full path instead of `cmd.exe` I always get this error:

```
char Process[] = "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe";
                STARTUPINFO sinfo;
                PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;
                memset(&sinfo, 0, sizeof(sinfo));
                sinfo.cb = sizeof(sinfo);
                sinfo.dwFlags = (STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW);
                sinfo.hStdInput = sinfo.hStdOutput = sinfo.hStdError = (HANDLE)mySocket;
                CreateProcess(NULL, Process, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sinfo, &pinfo);
                WaitForSingleObject(pinfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
                CloseHandle(pinfo.hProcess);
                CloseHandle(pinfo.hThread);
```

I always get:

***CreateProcessW(LPCWSTR,LPWSTR,LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,BOOL,DWORD,LPVOID,LPCWSTR,LPSTARTUPINFOW,LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'char [28]' to 'LPWSTR'   ConsoleApplication1***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a narrow character array instead of a wide character array.

Change your project's character encoding setting to MultiByte instead of Unicode so that `CreateProcess` uses `CreateProcessA` instead of `CreateProcessW`.

Or, use `wchar_t` (or `WCHAR`, which is a typedef available in Windows for `wchar_t`) instead of `char`:

```
wchar_t Process[] = L"C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe";
```

Or, you can change the code to use `CreateProcessA` manually:

```
char Process[] = "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe";
...
CreateProcessA(NULL, Process, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sinfo, &pinfo);
...
```

Comment: Note: if you rely on the project's character encoding, then you should use `TCHAR` instead of `char` or `wchar_t`: `TCHAR Process[] = TEXT("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe"); ... CreateProcess(NULL, Process, ...);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Agreed. TCHAR and other macros are recommended if the project should be compatible with both multibyte and unicode.